# C++ program behavior

Tags: c++, floating-point

Was demonstrating the failure of C++ to detect input issues in floating point numbers when additional characters follow the input.

E.G. 234.5 when using cin works fine, but 234.t (demonstrating a finger slip on input) would read the 234. and leave the t.

Imagine my surprise when some input fails and others did not. Note: These are not meant to be complex validators, just a demo to intro students that input can be tricky to validate.

*Program compiled on a Mac in Clion under C++ 14*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    float number = 0.0;
    int counter = 0;
    std::ifstream inData;
    inData.open("input.txt");

    inData >> number;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26;i++ ){
        if(inData.good()) {
            std::cout << "Good Row number: " << i << " " << static_cast<char>(i+97) << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "\tFail Row number: " << i << " " << static_cast<char>(i+97) << std::endl;
            inData.clear();
            inData.ignore(1, '\n');
        }

        inData >> number;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I ran this using this input file for curiosity sake

```
234.a
234.b
234.c
234.d
234.e
234.f
234.g
234.h
234.i
234.j
234.k
234.l
234.m
234.n
234.o
234.p
234.q
234.r
234.s
234.t
234.u
234.v
234.w
234.x
234.y
234.z
```

and this is the output:

```
    Fail Row number: 0 a
    Fail Row number: 1 b
    Fail Row number: 2 c
    Fail Row number: 3 d
    Fail Row number: 4 e
    Fail Row number: 5 f
Good Row number: 6 g
    Fail Row number: 7 h
Good Row number: 8 i
    Fail Row number: 9 j
    Fail Row number: 10 k
Good Row number: 11 l
    Fail Row number: 12 m
Good Row number: 13 n
    Fail Row number: 14 o
Good Row number: 15 p
    Fail Row number: 16 q
Good Row number: 17 r
    Fail Row number: 18 s
    Fail Row number: 19 t
Good Row number: 20 u
    Fail Row number: 21 v
    Fail Row number: 22 w
Good Row number: 23 x
    Fail Row number: 24 y
Good Row number: 25 z
```

Anyone have any clue as to what is going on?

Notes on comments:
-yes, using 'a' vs 97 is better, but part of the lesson is to emphasize that characters have a decimal value hence they are easy to compare.

- provided
- simplified for the core issue. I'll work on the second part for later.

Comment: Unrelated: Please don't introduce `i+97` as a way of creating the letters `'a'` and up. Use `'a'+i`.

Comment: What is the content of the files? The first version assumes one float per line, and the second one assumes two floats per line. One of those is clearly wrong, probably the second one.

Comment: Can you put the two versions of the program exactly as they are in the question (so that there is no question about what reads should be included and where) and also include the input you feed the program.

Comment: This is strange and very interesting behaviour. Voting to reopen, I hope someone understands what's going on.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with msvc. You can add output of number or run the program in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be one of the inconsistencies in parsing floating point numbers that occasionaly surface in the implementations of the standard library (see e.g. [1169](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1169), [2381](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2381)).

Consider the following modified snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    float number{};
    std::string test{ "234.0" };
    
    for(char ch{'a'}; ch <= 'z'; ++ch )
    {
        test.back() = ch;
        std::istringstream ss{ test };
        
        if (ss >> number)
            std::cout << ch << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/9xxhbo) you can see that, when compiled with Clang and `-stdlib=libc++` it produces the following output

```
g h j k l m o q r s t u v w y z
```

While `-stdlib=libstdc++` gives

```
a b c d f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z     // Only 'e' is rejected
```

Using [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof), all the cases are rejected (see e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Kjje7v)).

[`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

> (5) Extracts a floating-point value potentially skipping preceding whitespace. The value is stored to a given reference value.
> This function behaves as a [FormattedInputFunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction). After constructing and checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace, extracts a floating-point value by calling [std::num_get::get()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get).

The Standard specifies the behavior of `std::num_get::get()` at [28.4.3.2
[locale.num.get]](https://eel.is/c++draft/locale.num.get#general).

There are three stages

1. Determine a conversion specifier
2. Extract characters from in and determine a corresponding char value for the format expected by the conversion specification determined in stage 1.
3. Store results

The details of [stage 2](https://eel.is/c++draft/locale.num.get#facet.num.get.virtuals-3.2) mention that

> If it is not discarded, then a check is made to determine if c is allowed as the next character of an input field of the conversion specifier returned by Stage 1.
> If so, it is accumulated.

While on [stage 3](https://eel.is/c++draft/locale.num.get#facet.num.get.virtuals-3.3)

> The sequence of chars accumulated in stage 2 (the field) is converted to a numeric value by the rules of one of the functions declared in the header :
> [...]
> **For a float value, the function strtof**.
> [...]
> The numeric value to be stored can be one of:
>
> - zero, if the conversion function does not convert the entire field.
> - [...]
> - the converted value, otherwise.
>
> The resultant numeric value is stored in val.
> **If the conversion function does not convert the entire field**, or if the field represents a value outside the range of representable values, `ios_­base​::​failbit` is assigned to `err`.

Given the previous results, it appears that stage 2 is not correctly implemented in both the tested library.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I’ve run into odd behaviors of library code off and on. This one just stumped me as to why I got such a variety of response issues. 

As an aside some of the compilers would only work if I stripped the new line character after each input. So the option skipping white space seems to be implemented differently in different compilers. 

Thanks for the help!!